# Paranormal Book about Woman who moves into California house

Tags: story-identification

I was reading this book and remember some details and parts, but I never got to finish it. I can't find the book anywhere in my house, and it's driving me crazy.

Okay, so the book details are as follows (Note: they are not super detailed as my mind is kind of fuzzy, but I do hope it is enough to spark some plug in someone's mind who has read this book before.)

- The story is about a woman (I think she was a psychiatrist) who moves into a California house. I distinctly remember that she had a sister living with her in the house. Her sister was a musician, and she would stay up late or something playing music at the theater. Anyways, I know things got weird and paranormal-y, but I don't remember the exact details. There was something about a black cat in the story, some broken window, and, at some time, she went to a bookstore and read some sketchy book.
- Another important thing that I do remember is this. She fell in love with some guy, and when they were having sex, some lamp or light fell in the background. This is the exact line that I do remember because this was the part that I stopped on (it was the end of the chapter). "The air around her became electricity as he entered her. It was so electrifying that neither of them noticed the lamp fall behind them."
- Okay, now that I am remembering this a little clearly, I distinctly remember that she WAS a psychiatrist. Apparently, she had some telekinesis powers as well, and I think that is why she was having these weird dreams and things moving around kept scaring her.

I hope this helps and if you guys need any information, or if I remember anything, I will gladly update this post.

Once again, I really hope someone can help me find this book, as it has been driving me crazy for about two weeks now because I can't find it anywhere in my house, and I was so into it.

Thank you for taking the time to read this post. :)

**UPDATE:** I read this book like 5-6 years ago, and I know that it was an old book. It was a paperback edition. However, I just remembered about it, but I can't find the book any where. As per the character names, I sadly do not remember. The cat is not a major part of the book, I just know it was on the front cover of the book. The front cover had her house and the cat and a LOT of mist(might be key?).

Comment: Please update your question if you remember anything else (no matter how trivial) about the book: the name of a character, the name of the cat, etc. About how old is this book? How long ago did you read it? Paperback or hard cover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This book is "The Inheritor" by Marion Zimmer Bradley.

[image: cover]

From the [Amazon synopsis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312862938):

> Leslie Barnes has just bought her first home, overlooking San Francisco's Golden Gate Bridge. It seems the perfect place for Leslie and her sister, a brilliant young musician...but as soon as they move in, a plague of dark events begins, unsettling both women. To her horror, Leslie realizes that she is living in a vortex of magickal power. She must become the guardian of that power and protect it from those who seek to use it for evil. Trained as a psychologist, Leslie is in over her head when dealing with the occult--until she meets Claire Moffatt, a charming medium, and Claire's mentor, Colin MacLaren, world-famous psychic investigator. Together they stand against evil and enable Leslie to claim her full inheritance.

Comment: Thank you :) This book isn't available anywhere though! And even when I searched Marion Zimmer Bradley books, "The Inheritor" didn't show up! Wow...

Comment: @G_as_in_Gnome, it looks like you can buy it right from the link above the quote.  When I follow the link it gives me a buying option. I read this way back when it first came out in '84.  It had a different cover, so there must have been a second printing.

Comment: yeah mine also has a different front cover. I just found my copy! It has red devilish letters, and, what I am assuming is Leslie Barnes, on the front cover with her hand up in some sort of karate pose. And like I mentioned, there is a lot of mist. Thanks anyways though, this has rid me of two nights of sleep deprivation :P